# Node.js File System returning empty array of files

Tags: node.js

I'm getting an empty array [], when running this code. I would like to return a list of all all the files in the directory, how can I do this?

```
function returnListofFiles(){

    var file_list = [];

    fs.readdir(genresChartFolder, (err, files) => {

      files.forEach(file_ => {

        if(file_ === library){

            fs.readdir(genresChartFolder+file_, (err, files) => {

              files.forEach(file => {

                  if(path.extname(file) == ".json"){

                        file_list.push(file);
                  }

              })

            })

        }

      })

    })

    return file_list;

}
```

Comment: try  file_list.push(file); instead of if(path.extname(file) == ".json"){

                        file_list.push(file);
                  }

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` returns array of items found in the directory without trailing slash. So, this `genresChartFolder+file_` should not work.

Example:
If `fs.readdir(genresChartFolder...)` returns `['test', 'app.js']` then you should do something like this `fs.readdir(genresChartFolder + '/' + file_ ...)`.